# How to use tags in loot table pool conditions?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-behavior-packs

I'm trying to build a loot table for a Minecraft Bedrock behavior pack. The "entries" section is behaving as desired, but the "conditions" section is not. I am trying to make it give the below loot only if the block was mined with a pickaxe. Right now, the loot drops regardless of what tool was used to break it.

Can I use tag queries, or am I going to have to make a different pool for each pickaxe type?

```
{
    "type": "minecraft:block",
    "pools": [
        {
            "rolls": 1,
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "condition": "match_tool",
                    "item": {
                        "tags": "query.any_tag('pickaxes')"
                    },
                    "count": 1
                }
            ],
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "name": "test:my_custom_item",
                    "weight": 1,
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "set_count",
                            "count": {
                                "min": 1,
                                "max": 4
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```